# is it recommended in codeigniter to always include the basepath?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

is it recommend to always put the code below in every file in Code igniter?

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

Answer (score 2):

Although is not mandatory, that line ensures all requests done to the script had to go through `index.php` file where `BASEPATH` constant is actually defined.

Comment: thanks for your reply. i have a follow up question. should i include this in my views file also? or should i only put this on controller and model?

Comment: It is not mandatory neither in controllers, but it can be set in any php file that lives in `application` directory.

Answer (score 0):

No mandatory at all, to make cool site, you can modify your url, with uri libraries.

Ex: yoursite.com/clothes/man

https://www.google.co.id/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/uri.html&ved=0ahUKEwipn_XakczUAhWJqo8KHRzmA8kQFggeMAA&usg=AFQjCNF0cuVo9HL1rzm510BB0RIU30HOng